# Does the study of mythology find evidence of Jung's "Universal Psychic Structure?"

Tags: origins

Are there universal myths, regardless of culture, that we retell over and over?
The example often used is The Cosmic Hunt.

Comment: There are hundreds of them.  There are dozens of proposed explanations for it from various authors.  This is very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like Chenmunka says, there are dozens of proposed explanations for it from various authors, but who bring light to this matter on the past century was really Jung. There's a plenty of studies of Carl Jung (this studies where the source was Alchemical books and alchemists). In Alchemy itself you will find various explanations of this Universal Structure. The issue is the language-code of this sources are confuse for many poeple.

But you can check here for good quite examples! https://www.hccfl.edu/media/724354/archetypesforliteraryanalysis.pdf

I'm sure it's gonna be a good start.

Comment: Glad that I helped! see ya